# Fabric canvas text to read html tag

Tags: fabricjs

I am trying to make a image editor like yourquote.
I am using fabric js for editor.
I am doing it on website not app.
I have used 2 different url. On first url I want user to enter text and on second url I am letting the user decorate the text and make it image.

My regular text is working as I am posting the text to url, but when I am maintaining line break it is not working.

How can it be possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Its solved 
I added '\n' after each line break and sent the final string to next URL and the fabric js canvas loaded exact what I wanted.